# Using GetDirectories() To Return Folder Path When Access Is Denied

Tags: c#, .net, directory, file-access

Assume we have:

- Folder C:\FolderA
- A Single Subfolder C:\FolderA\FolderB
- User B is the Owner of FolderB, and has Full Control of FolderB
- No other ACL's exist for FolderB
- User A Has Access to FolderA and can see FolderB but cannot open it

What I want to do, is return the directory path of FolderB, however

```
string[] folders = 
Directory.GetDirectories(@"C:\FolderA\", "*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
```

Will return access denied, although in explorer I clearly have access to list directories.  I want to get the full path of the directory GetDirectries Failed on so I can then add new ACL's programmatically.  How do I get that path?

Comment: I've tested this scenario and it works for me. Can you please specify all permissions UserA has on FolderA?

Comment: Also, please let me know if the permissions are just for the folder, folder and files, or folder subfolders and files